# css3 transformed element not firing events onClick

Tags: javascript, events, css, transform, css-transitions

//edit my brain was in a knot. Everything works as it should, this question is false and obsolete

If I rotateY an Element and try to click on the element, which has a bound eventListener (onClick), the event will not fire (hovering is also off). If I remove the transformation, the event fires as expected.
I know, that by doing a transform, the element only appears at a different location, but "actually is still at its original position". But it seems idiotic to let one transform an element, but kill all its eventListeners..? Any direction I should dig into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're using raw JavaScript or jQuery, but I have no problem:

---

```
div {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
Background: blue;
-WebKit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(100px, 100px);
}
```

---

```
$('div').click(function(){
$(this).hide();
});
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/JNM6x/

---

Maybe you can post your code? It could be something else that's giving you trouble.

Comment: Oh oops, forgot to make that cross browser... Just change the vendor prefix if you're using Firefox or something else.

Comment: thank you for making a fiddle! My brain was in a knot. I had an alert that should trigger onClick, but had other alerts fire before where I clicked "prevent other dialogs".. So everything was working. Thank you for untying my brain :)